# OWOX BI Big Query Add-on issue

Tags: google-bigquery

[Query Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRXIf.jpg)
[Data Upload Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F37DW.jpg)

I kept having this problem popped up when I run the query on OWOX add on google sheet. both seem to have the same error which is the "Job not found" thing.

I've tried using different projects, and datasets and it still didn't work.
Additional Note: When I successfully ran the query in OWOX add on, there was a query history in BigQuery but there was no report generated in the google sheet. There was no any error as well, I really need help on this thanks.

Comment: Can you provide scree shot and more details to help  with the troubleshooting

Comment: ive changed the screenshot and what details u want?

Answer (score 1):

Not found means either owox are not sending the correct projectId when calling bq or your table is not located in the default US/EU location. I suggest you try standard sql to see if it help assuming this is not the later. If not working I guess you will need to approach owox team for help

Comment: must it be in the default US/EU location in order to do that?

Comment: Great. Please consider voting for the answer.